# Limiting a left join to returning one result?

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I currently have this left join as part of a query:

```
LEFT JOIN movies t3 ON t1.movie_id = t3.movie_id AND t3.popularity = 0
```

The trouble is that if there are several movies with the same name and same popularity (don't ask, it just is that way :-) ) then duplicate results are returned.

All that to say, I would like to limit the result of the left join to one.

I tried this:

```
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT t3.movie_name FROM movies t3 WHERE t3.popularity = 0 LIMIT 1)
     ON t1.movie_id = t3.movie_id AND t3.popularity = 0
```

The second query dies with the error:

```
Every derived table must have its own alias
```

I know what I'm asking is slightly vague since I'm not providing the full query, but is what I'm asking generally possible?

Comment: that is the last left join, right? you're not going `LEFT JOIN ... ON ... AND ... LEFT JOIN ...` are you?  and is `LIMIT 1` at the end of your statement not what you're after?

Comment: Have a look at the `DISTINCT`statement, maybe that can solve your problem.

Comment: @jared - it is the last `LEFT JOIN` in the query, yes. There are two more before it. I can't just stick `LIMIT 1` at the end, however, because the query as a whole returns many rows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL JOIN the most recent row only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619030/mysql-join-the-most-recent-row-only)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The error is clear -- you just need to create an alias for the subquery following its closing `)` and use it in your `ON` clause since every table, derived or real, must have its own identifier. Then, you'll need to include `movie_id` in the subquery's select list to be able to join on it.   Since the subquery already includes `WHERE popularity = 0`, you don't need to include it in the join's `ON` clause.

```
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    movie_id, 
    movie_name 
  FROM movies 
  WHERE popularity = 0
  ORDER BY movie_name
  LIMIT 1
) the_alias ON t1.movie_id = the_alias.movie_id
```

If you are using one of these columns in the outer `SELECT`, reference it via `the_alias.movie_name` for example.

#### Update after understanding the requirement better:

To get one per group to join against, you can use an aggregate `MAX()` or `MIN()` on the `movie_id` and group it in the subquery. No subquery `LIMIT` is then necessary -- you'll receive the first `movie_id` per name with`MIN()` or the last with `MAX()`.

```
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    movie_name,
    MIN(movie_id) AS movie_id
  FROM movies
  WHERE popularity = 0
  GROUP BY movie_name
) the_alias ON t1.movie_id = the_alias.movie_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I rewrote the query to make it as in your example and it almost is working, but not quite. If I remove `LIMIT 1` from the statement, then it returns multiple results (movie names) as before, but if I leave `LIMIT 1` in the query then no movie names are returned. Any idea why that would be? Thanks again.

Comment: @Nate That's a bit weird. I put in an explicit `ORDER BY` (which should have been there) but I don't think that's the reason.

Comment: @Nate Run the subquery by itself and verify that it returns the correct row with the WHERE clause you have.

Comment: @Nate and what's your MySQL version? Older versions did not support `LIMIT` in subqueries, though it works since 5.0 at least.

Comment: I see what's happening. It's returning the movie name (in my example) for the first row in the table, not for the current movie. I.e. if I add `AND movie_id = 2` after `WHERE popularity = 0` then it returns the movie name for that id. I tried adding `AND movie_id = t1.movie_id`, but that dies with the error `Unknown column 't1.movie_id' in 'where clause'`. Hmm..

Comment: @Nate the `movie_id = t1.movie_id` is covered by the join `ON` clause. I would need to see your full query to diagnose further.

Comment: Michael, won't the query: `SELECT movie_id, movie_name FROM movies WHERE popularity = 0 ORDER BY movie_name LIMIT 1` just retrieve the first row in the table `movies` (ordered by movie_name)? I think that's what's happening..

Comment: @Nate Yes, and I appear to have misunderstood your requirement entirely. If you want only one per group to join against, you'll need a max() aggregate. Stay tuned for a minute and I'll update...

Comment: You sir, are a genius! It works beautifully! I suppose now I should try to actually understand how it works :-) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much, doing the bracket select at start of left join was what I needed.

Comment: does this have any performance implication as compared to a simple left join?

Answer (score 10):

```
LEFT JOIN movies as m ON m.id = (
    SELECT id FROM movies mm WHERE mm.movie_id = t1.movie_id
    ORDER BY mm.id DESC
    LIMIT 1    
)
```

Answer (score 2):

you could try to add `GROUP BY t3.movie_id` to the first query

Answer (score 2):

On MySQL 5.7+ use `ANY_VALUE & GROUP_BY`:

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.movie_name, ANY_VALUE(t3.popularity) popularity
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t3 ON (t3.movie_id=t1.movie_id AND t3.popularity=0)
GROUP BY t1.id
```

more info
[LEFT JOIN only first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626493/left-join-only-first-row/61522263#61522263)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
LEFT JOIN 
    (
     SELECT t3.movie_name, t3.popularity   
     FROM movies t3 WHERE t3.popularity = 0 LIMIT 1
    ) XX
     ON  t1.movie_id = XX.movie_id AND XX.popularity = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id,movie_name FROM movies GROUP BY id
) as m ON (
   m.id = x.id 
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy solution to left join the 1 most/least recent row is using select over ON phrase

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Name, B.Content
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM B WHERE id = A.id)
```

Where A.id is the auto-incremental primary key.

Comment: you can't use A inside a subquery, postgres
```
ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "A"
SQL state: 42P01
Hint: There is an entry for table "A", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.```

Answer (score -2):

```
// Mysql

SELECT SUM(db.item_sales_nsv) as total FROM app_product_hqsales_otc as db 
LEFT JOIN app_item_target_otc as it ON 
db.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM app_item_target_otc  as ot WHERE id = db.id) 
and db.head_quarter = it.hqcode 
AND db.aaina_item_code = it.aaina_item_code AND db.month = it.month 
AND db.year = it.year
WHERE db.head_quarter = 'WIN001' AND db.month = '5' AND db.year = '2022' AND db.status = '1'
```