# SQL: Left join but select only one row with least created date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say I have this table:

Table A:

```
 id   name    
---   ---  
 1    John
```

Table B:

```
  id     content    Aid      Date
  ---      ---      ---     ----------
  100      abc       1      2017-02-03 11:16:00
  101      xyz       1      2017-02-03 11:50:00
```

I want to join A and B such that the resulting table has only the one row from B with Date = minimum.

My desired output:

```
 id   name  content
---   ---   ------
 1    John    abc
```

My failed attempt at joining is giving me (1, John, xyz) row as well:

```
SELECT A.[id], A.[name], B.[content]
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.id = B.Aid
```

Later I tried doing a WHERE inside join but I'm not able to construct it:

```
SELECT A.[id], A.[name]
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.id = (SELECT Aid FROM B WHERE Date = (SELECT MIN(Date) FROM B 
WHERE <no idea where I'm going?>)
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limiting a left join to returning one result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388443/limiting-a-left-join-to-returning-one-result)

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT A.[id], A.[name],B.[content]
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.id = B.Aid
AND B.Date = (Select Min(Date) from B as B2 where B2.Aid=A.id)
```

Comment: If multiple values are present in A and B, still your query is giving me only 1 row in the result set. This row is pivoting on the first entry in B with least created date. Shouldn't the subquery be Select Min(Date) from B WHERE xyz?

Comment: This works out of the box

Answer (score 3):

You can use a left join to a derived table:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name, b.Content
FROM a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT aId, content, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY aId ORDER BY Date) rn
    FROM b        
) b ON(a.Id = b.AId AND b.rn = 1)
```

The `row_number` window function will start with 1 for each `aId` with the minimum date, so you need to add the condition `AND b.rn = 1` to the on clause. 
If you would have added it to the `where` clause, it would affectivly change your left join to an inner join.

Comment: thanks for your answer! this is working as expected. can you take a look at Mithilesh's answer? I tried running both but there is no difference in the runtime. I'm not sure which one to choose. Can you help?

Comment: I think you will only see a difference in run time with a large set of records for both tables. As to which one you should choose - well, I would say go with the one you find easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OUTER APPLY.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name, b.Content
FROM a
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT  TOP (1) *
    FROM b
    WHERE b.aid = a.id
    ORDER BY Date ASC
) b
```

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use SELECT TOP 1 with ORDER BY B.Date DESC ?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution to left join the 1 most/least recent row is using select over ON phrase

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Name, B.Content
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM B WHERE id = A.id)
```

Comment: Don't answer these duplicate questions, flag them as duplicates. [answer] [Help]