# Define which row to use for join

Tags: sql

I have a table with products and another table with the names of these products (a product can have several names in different languages).

I currently use a query like this to list the names of all products:

```
SELECT name
FROM name_table
LEFT JOIN product_table ON name_table.product = product_table.product
ORDER BY name_table.product, language != 'en', language != '*'
```

This would yield a list of all names and the best available name (english if there is one, then an international name, if neither exists any name) would always appear first. I just skip over all entries after the first for each product - not elegant but it works fast enough.

The problem with this is that I cannot sort alphabetically.

However, when I use something like this:

```
SELECT
  product,
 (SELECT name
  FROM name_table
  WHERE name_table.product = product_table.product
  ORDER BY language != 'en'
  LIMIT 1) AS bestname
FROM product_table
ORDER BY bestname
```

then the query is extremely slow (at least with MySQL).

This query is fast but it seems to be undefined (therefore quasi-random) what name row is used:

```
SELECT name
FROM product_table
LEFT JOIN name_table ON name_table.product = product_table.product
ORDER BY name
```

If I only could tell MySQL what row to use for the join, then all would be fine.

Is there a way to define which row is used in a join if several matching rows exist?

Edit: Products can have names in any languages and not all products have an english name, sorry for the confusion.

Edit2: I have found an equivalent question: [MySQL JOIN the most recent row only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619030/mysql-join-the-most-recent-row-only?rq=1)
There, the SQL-gurus also used sub-selects (my subselect-query is extremely slow so I want to avoid it), so maybe SQL cannot do what I want :-(

Comment: How do you define the best available name?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get just the English names for the products?  This your question suggests:

```
SELECT name
FROM name_table LEFT JOIN
     product_table ON name_table.product = product_table.product
where language = 'en'
ORDER BY name_table.product
```

Or, are you trying to get the foreign names, but order the products by their English name?  If so, you need an additional join:

```
SELECT name
FROM name_table LEFT JOIN
     product_table 
     ON name_table.product = product_table.product and
        name_table.language <> 'en' left outer join
     product_table pten
     on name_table.product = product_table.product and
        name_table.language = 'en'
ORDER BY pten.name, name_table.product_id
```

This assumes that there is only one English name for a product.  The second clause of the sort is for the case where there is no English name, to keep all the other names together.

Comment: My impression is that you'd want to include the `language = 'en'` filter in the join condition of the first query also.

Comment: Not all products have an english name, also there can be several english names for each product. (The real tables are a bit more complicated, there is also a priority-column, alias-flag, etc.) - Basically what I want to do is join not only a specific condition (LEFT JOIN ON bla = ble AND blo <> blu) but to use the best available that fits that condition.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've defined your queries it doesn't appear you need to join to the product table at all.

If name_table has the product column, language column, AND the name you're trying to get, why is there a join to product_table?  Please clarify, I think I might know what you need to do, but the question is worded in a confusing manner to me.

Comment: Agreed. I think part of the confusion is whether all products have at least an English name.

Comment: Sorry about that: Products can have no english name, one english name or several english names, it's completely arbitrary. Basically what I am trying to do is choose the best available name.