# mySQL: How to join users with user_logs returning the latest log only?

Tags: php, mysql, join

Hi Guys i have 2 tables (user/logs kinda thing)

tk_assets (the users)
tk_sessions (the logs) <-- where each log contains both stamp_in and stamp_out epoch values (making up 1 session of the user.

User is considered logged in when its latest session does not have a stamp_out value (still logged in)

I simply need to retrieve all users in the database along its "LATEST SESSION"..

In plain english, this would be 
"SELECT each user as well as its most recent session"

I can't seem to figure out the proper SQL statement for this..

```
SELECT
tk_assets.ass_id,
tk_sessions.stamp_in,
tk_sessions.stamp_out
FROM
tk_assets
LEFT JOIN tk_sessions ON tk_assets.ass_id = tk_sessions.ass_id
GROUP BY
tk_sessions.ass_id
ORDER BY
tk_sessions.stamp_in DESC
```

this is as far as i got..

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need other information, `MAX` should help you out.

```
SELECT u.*, MAX(l.stamp_out) FROM user u
INNER JOIN logs l ON l.user_id = u.id
WHERE l.stamp_out = 0
GROUP BY u.id
```

If you need more that that, take a look at this question: [MySQL JOIN the most recent row only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619030/mysql-join-the-most-recent-row-only)

Answer (score 0):

Yoh your naming conventions are a bit rough

```
SELECT assets.`ass_id`, sessions.`stamp_in`, sessions.`stamp_out`, sessions.`ass_id`
FROM tk_assets assets
LEFT JOIN tk_sessions sessions
ON assets.`ass_id` = sessions.`ass_id`
WHERE assets.`ass_id` = sessions.`ass_id`
GROUP BY sessions.`ass_id`
ORDER BY sessions.`stamp_in` DESC
```