# What Am I Missing? MySQL Left Join Most Newest Entry From 2nd Table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I need a fresh pair of eyes on this. I have two tables, one of which has users and the second which contains login records, multiple records for each user. What I'm trying to do is select *all* entries from the first table, and the most recent record from the second table, e.g., a list of all users but only show the most recent activity. Both tables have auto increment in the ID column.

My code currently is thus:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, u.email, r.rid, r.user_id
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN login_records AS r ON r.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE
   r.rid = (
      SELECT MAX( rid )
      FROM login_records
      WHERE user_id = u.user_id
   )
```

I've scoured answers to similar questions on SO and tried all of them, but results have been either returning *nothing* or only getting odd results (not necessarily the newest one). ID in both tables is auto-increment, so I thought it should be a relatively simple matter to get the only or highest ID for a particular user, but it either returns nothing or a completely different selection each time.

It's my first time using JOIN - do I have the wrong JOIN? Do I need to ORDER or GROUP things differently?

Thanks for your help. It's got to be something simple, since Danny Coulombe's answer [appearing here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619030/mysql-join-the-most-recent-row-only/35965649#35965649) seems to work for other users.

Comment: Can you share the structures of both tables?

Comment: Why use `rid` when there's `record_id` ?

Comment: I think it should be -- LEFT JOIN login_records AS r ON u.user_id = r.user_id as the join will fetch data from the table on the left of the JOIN condition.

Comment: @LukStorms fixed. It’s rid in both places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a subquery I believe:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2wudMDVxReYJz4FEyG19Va/0

```
CREATE TABLE users (
user_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL 
  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE users_logins (
user_login_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL 
  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO users SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO users SELECT 2;

INSERT INTO users_logins SELECT 1,1;
INSERT INTO users_logins SELECT 2,1;
INSERT INTO users_logins SELECT 3,1;
INSERT INTO users_logins SELECT 4,1;
INSERT INTO users_logins SELECT 5,2;
INSERT INTO users_logins SELECT 6,2;
```

And the query:

```
SELECT 
u.user_id, ul.latest_login_id
FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT user_id, MAX(user_login_id) latest_login_id
      FROM users_logins
      GROUP BY user_id
    ) ul ON u.user_id = ul.user_id
```

Comment: You sir are awesome...that did the trick. I've gone through things trying to normalize my tables, and it's worked okay up until this which has kept me stumped for 4 days...thank you for your help! 

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing all `rid` in where clause and corrolated subquery by `record_id`?

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, u.email, r.rid, r.record_id, r.user_id
FROM test_users AS u
LEFT JOIN test_login_records AS r ON r.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE 
 (r.record_id = (
   SELECT MAX(record_id)
   FROM test_login_records
      WHERE user_id = u.user_id
  ) OR r.record_id is null);
```

Test [here](http://rextester.com/ZZVBO52659)

Comment: This will leave out all users that never logged in. If this desireable - then query ahoi!

Comment: @madflow Heh, you're right.  Well spotted.  Those won't have a max record_id.  Oh well, that's easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **ORDER BY** with what column you want to display by desc, for example **ORDER BY last_login DESC**.

Change the last_login column with the column you want to order, but you must first declare the last_login column after **SELECT**.