# How to JOIN a table on an aggregate

Tags: mysql

## Issue Summary:

I need to join a single row to a table output based on an aggregate function, in this case of most recent corresponding record. Various other questions on this topic seem to work on the basis that both tables values are required (`INNER JOIN`, etc.) but in my case the aggregate needs to work on a `LEFT JOIN` table that is many times going to be `NULL`.

MySQL 5.7;
Here is an couple of illistrative tables:

## Tables

```
Core_data:
-----------

create table `core`
(
core_id int(8) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
some_name varchar(80) null,
some_data varchar(80) null,
some_values .... etc. 
)


Linked_data:
------------

create table `linked_data`
(
link_id smallint(6) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
core_id int(8) unsigned
data_date date,
some_linked_data_values varchar(80) null
)
```

I have a query dealing with dozens of tables. selecting 1 row from the Core table and selecting various `LEFT JOIN` data from dozens of other tables.

The illustrated linked data table has data that is dated, and the date is important, that only the most recent is returned.

## Example Data:

```
linked_data
------------

link_id | core_id |  data_date  | data_value | ...
-------------------------------------------------
   1    |    2    |  2020-09-03 |  something | ...
   2    |    4    |  2019-07-29 |  whatever  | ...
   3    |    1    |  2017-11-09 |    yews    | ...
   4    |    4    |  2018-04-10 |    socks   | ...
```

I want to only join the row with core_id = 4 AND the maximum date value. How can I create this within the `JOIN` scenario; I can't put the `MAX` aggregate into the `JOIN ... ON` condition.

## My Current SQL:

My SQL is something like this:

```
   SELECT ... many columns ..., 
   ld.data_value,
   ld.data_date,
   more.columns ... 
   FROM core
   LEFT JOIN table1 ON core.core_id = table1.core_id
   LEFT JOIN table2 ON core.core_id = table2.core_id
   LEFT JOIN table3 ON core.core_id = table3.core_id
   ... etc ...
   LEFT JOIN linked_data ld ON core.core_id = ld.core_id AND MAX(ld.data_date)
   WHERE ... core_id = value
```

One table I need only a result row that has the highest value of a column (data based), there is no reason for `linked_data` to hold any data so the LEFT JOIN may return NULL

## Expected result:

For `core_id = 4` I want to be able to output a single SQL row result containing `linked_data.data_value = whatever` . For `core_id = 5` I want to be able to output the rest of the data but nothing from `linked_data.` table.

## What Have I tried already?

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3619209/3536236) is noted as correct but is also noted that it will become very slow very quickly with larger amounts of data.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35965649/3536236) put the qualifier in the `WHERE` clause, but there's no promise that `linked_data` will contain any result at all so, I can of course add further conditionals (check if  into the `WHERE` clause here but I was hoping to avoid this.
- [This MySQL post](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,150911) has another possible solution but comments on this also state it is very slow (that may be user error on their part, I've not tested it yet).
- I have also tried using a SELECT in the LEFT JOIN like so:

  ```
   SELECT ... many columns ..., 
   ld.data_value,
   ld.data_date,
   more.columns ... 
   FROM core
   LEFT JOIN table1 ON core.core_id = table1.core_id
   LEFT JOIN table2 ON core.core_id = table2.core_id
   LEFT JOIN table3 ON core.core_id = table3.core_id
   ... etc ...
   LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT linked_data FROM linked_data ldi WHERE core.core_id = ldi.core_id AND MAX(ldi.data_date) 
   ) as ld ON core.core_id = ldi.core_id
   WHERE ... core_id = value
  ```

Referenced from [this Q&A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56716/80979)

But this still tells me **Aggregate calls are not allowed here**

> EDIT: I found why the aggregate wasn't allowed; a simple syntax mistake on my part; but I have put up a full answer to clarify this Q&A as I couldn't find any relative answers when I was searching, so this may be useful to someone.

If anyone has a more correct way of solving the original issue please share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing out this whole question, I found that a simple syntax fix on my latest example SQL resolved the correct way to do this (and I've done this in the past the correct way but had not learnt it).

I note the lack of (or rather my inability to easily find) a clear definitive answer on the Interwebs to my query, so here's my methodology...

The correct way to do this type of aggregated join with respect to getting 0 or 1 results from the joined table is as follows:

- `LEFT JOIN` and then wrap the subquery in brackets and set it `as ...` as per usual.
- Put the aggregation function into the subquery ignoring the join criteria; the join criteria will be in the outer query `ON ...`  section.
- use `ORDER BY` in the sub query and then set the aggregate at that point.

So;

```
   SELECT ... many columns ..., 
   ld.data_value,
   ld.data_date,
   more.columns ... 
   FROM core
   LEFT JOIN table1 ON core.core_id = table1.core_id
   LEFT JOIN table2 ON core.core_id = table2.core_id
   LEFT JOIN table3 ON core.core_id = table3.core_id
   ... etc ...
   LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT linked_data FROM linked_data ldi WHERE optional = 1 ORDER BY MAX(ldi.data_date) 
   ) as ld ON core.core_id = ldi.core_id
   WHERE ... core_id = value
```

There is no need for a `WHERE` in the subquery but obviously if you do then it should be static and not need to reference the outer table, as that's done on the `ON` clause. I put in `WHERE optional = 1` for familiarity.

The nature of `LEFT JOIN` is it will return 0 or 1 results so I find there's no need for much else.

If anyone has a better way of solving my original issue please let me know!

P.s> *I have not efficiency tested this answer at all.*

Answer (score 1):

In its shortest sample answer for you from what provided... You can have a pre-query resulting in an alias for the join.  This pre-query can group / max per Core.

That said, and since the linked-data table is auto-increment, I would assume (yeah, I know about assume, but you can confirm) that as each record is added, the date will always be the date added.  So and ID of 100 may have a date of Jan 14, 2020, you would never have an earlier date record with a higher ID such as ID 101 = Nov 3, 2019.  As each ID added, higher date than last record regardless of the core id.

You can then continue your additional "left-joins" to other tables as needed.

**REVISION FROM COMMENT CLARIFICATION**

Martin, from the clarification you provided about the data coming from multiple sources and the date could represent older data, just revise the pre-query inner sql to the following.  The query is heavily commented to clarify how the over/partition query works in this scenario

Now, integrating with all the rest of your stuff.  I will only join to your primary core table as a left-join

```
select
      cd.core_id,
      cd.some_name,
      cd.some_data,
      cd.some_values,
      ld2.link_id,
      ld2.data_date,
      ld2.some_linked_data_values
   from
      core_data cd
         left join
         ( select pq1.* 
             from
               -- first, all columns I want to have returned from 
               -- the linked_data table
               ( select core_id, 
                        data_date, 
                        link_id, 
                        -- dense_rank() returns sequential counter value
                        -- starting at 1 based on every change of the 
                        -- PARTITION BY Core_ID in next part below
                        dense_rank() 
                    over ( partition by 
                              -- primary sorting by the core_id
                              core_id 
                           order by 
                              -- then within each core_id, descending by date
                              data_date desc, 
                              -- and then by the link_id descending, just in case
                              -- there are multiple records for the same core_id
                              -- AND the same date... So you get the most
                              -- recently added linked_data record for given core
                              link_id desc ) as sqlrow
                    from linked_data ) pq1
            where
               -- now, from inner partition/over query, only get the record
               -- where the sqlrow = 1, as result of dense_rank()
               -- that resets to 1 every time core_id changes
               pq1.sqlrow=1 ) PQ
             on cd.core_id = PQ.core_id
                LEFT JOIN linked_data ld2
                   on PQ.Link_id = ld2.link_id
```

The inner query with OVER / PARTITION BY is basically making a first-pass of the data and ordering it first by the partition (the core id), then sub-sorted by the data_date DESCENDING (so most recent date first regardless of being added earlier or later from the import from whatever external sources), then sub-sorted by link_id descending based on the most recent record added for any given date.

The final outer WHERE clause is basically stating only give me back the first row for every core_id.  So now, you have the proper critical elements to re-do the LEFT join back to the original core ID, yet have the proper link_id to get the proper record at your final query result.

Comment: Thanks. The Date of the `data_date` column is not the date added to this system, there is no guarentee that the most recent record has the most recent date. Records come in from various sources and sometimes are years old

Comment: @Martin, see revision and edited query with over/partition implemented