# How to count how many addresses made the 2nd purchase after submitting return request?

Tags: mysql

The Return table looks like:

| Order_id | Address | Return_request_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Address1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 23456 | Address2 | 2022-03-04 |

The Order table looks like:

| Order_id | Address | Order_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Address1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 12346 | Address1 | 2022-01-03 |

How to count how many addresses made the 2nd purchase after submitting return request?

What I have tried but doesn't really works:

```
select count(distinct r.address)
from return r left join order o on r.address = o.address
where o.order_date > r.return_request_date
```

Comment: Please explain "doesn't really work"; does it not work at all or does it work but is slow, etc.?

Comment: Hi, the table structure is a bit complicated. Even though I narrowed down the constraints a lot, the code still ran for more than 15 minutes without any results, so I'm trying to understand if there's something wrong with my own code logic.

Comment: to be honest, there's something wrong with your question!  What exactly are you trying to do?  Can you show a complete example of what the data looks like and what result you are trying to obtain?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT ot.order_id, MAX(rt.return_request_date) as mrrd 
    FROM orders_table ot
    INNER JOIN returns_table rt ON ot.order_id = rt.order_id 
    HAVING ot.order_date >= mrrd
```

This above SQL will almost certainly need some refining but the process here is to:

- Select ONLY the order Id's which have at least one returned order id in place (via the `INNER JOIN`)
- Select only the maximum `order_return_request` date from the join
- and `HAVING` the order date is later than this maximum `return_request_date`.

Without using `HAVING` you'd need to use Subquery SELECTs which *might* be illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619030/mysql-join-the-most-recent-row-only) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66033916/how-to-join-a-table-on-an-aggregate).